# Compare dictionaries and delete key:value pairs

Tags: python-2.7, subset, defaultdict

I have two list dictionaries.

```
big_dict = defaultdict(list)
small_dict defaultdict(list)


big_dict = {StepOne:[{PairOne:{key1: value1}}, {PairTwo:{key2: value2}}, {PairThree: {key3: value3}}]}


small_dict = {key1: value1}
```

Is it possible found subset of second dictionary in 'StepOne' and delete another sub-dictionaries in 'StepOne' key?

Comment: Can you provide expected output? From how it seems to me you want to delete PairOne: dict?

Comment: @atru I excpected see something like this:
big_dict = {StepOne:{PairOne:{key1: value1}}}

As you can see, all another nested dicts should be deleted. Problem is that big_dict creates dynamically every time. And I don't know which keys nested dicts has

Comment: You mean erase everything besides the things that are part of the small dict?

Comment: @atru yes. You're right. Erase all nested dict except founded.

Comment: Instead, are PairOne, PairTwo subdicts inside of StepOne? If they are please fix your question -  they don't appear to be.

Comment: @artu I'm affraid that I can't :) Because algorithm has two variables on input. And algorithm creates big_dict from 7x7 matrix depends from input values. Every cell in matrix has from 1 to 3 values. So, dictionary has tree-view in finally.  I skipped first two dicts that algorithm creates on the first steps and  published latest short tree. 

And what I want get now is compress this tree by deleting redundant "leaves"

Comment: Sounds complicated :) Ok, on it. I'm creating something simple. But please clarify about that StepOne thing.

Comment: @artu, thank you for remark. I corrected my mistake, I guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet there is a more pythonic way to do it, but this should solve your problem:

```
big_dict = {'A0':[{'a':{'ab':1}, 'b':{'bb':2}, 'c':{'cc':3}}], 'A1':[{'b':{'bb':1}, 'c':{'bb':5}, 'd':{'cc':3}}]}

small_dict = {'bb':2, 'cc':3}

for big_key in big_dict.keys():
    for nested_key in big_dict[big_key][0].keys():
        ls_small = [ x for x in small_dict if x in big_dict[big_key][0][nested_key]]
        if not ls_small:
            del big_dict[big_key][0][nested_key]
        else:
            ls_small = [ y for y in ls_small if small_dict[y] is big_dict[big_key][0][nested_key][y]]
            if not ls_small:
                del big_dict[big_key][0][nested_key]
        ls_small = []
```

I've added another main dictionary, `'A1'` to make it more representative. What this does is it loops through keys of the main dictionary (`'A0'`, `'A1'`) and then through keys of the first set of nested dictionaries (`'a', 'b',...`). It selects the nested dictionaries as the 1st element of the lists - values of the main dictionaries.

For each nested dictionary it checks if any of the keys in `small_dict` are part of it's subdictionary. The sibdictionary is fetched by `big_dict[big_key][nested_key]` since it's the value of the nested dictionary. If the `small_dict` keys are found in the subdictionary, they are temporarily stored in `ls_small`.

If `ls_small` for that nested dictionary is empty after key-checking step it means no keys from `small_dict` are present in that nested dictionary and the nested dictionary is deleted. If it is not empty, the `else` part checks for matching of the values - again deleting the entry if the values don't match.

The output for this example is:

```
{'A1': [{'d': {'cc': 3}}], 'A0': [{'c': {'cc': 3}, 'b': {'bb': 2}}]}
```

Note - as it is right now, the approach will keep the nested dictionary if only one `small_dict` key:value pair matches, meaning that an input of this form

```
big_dict = {'A0':[{'a':{'bb':2}, 'b':{'bb':2, 'cc': 5}, 'c':{'cc':3}}], 'A1':[{'b':{'bb':1}, 'c':{'bb':5}, 'd':{'cc':3}}]}
```

will produce

```
{'A1': [{'d': {'cc': 3}}], 'A0': [{'a': {'bb': 2}, 'c': {'cc': 3}, 'b': {'cc': 5, 'bb': 2}}]}
```

Is this the desired behavior?

Comment: I should check it now. Few minutes, please!

Comment: Your algo returns error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'**

If you see on big_dict, this is defaultdict(list). And this dict has list structure: 

`big_dict = {StepOne:[{PairOne:{key1: value1}}, {PairTwo:{key2: value2}}, {PairThree: {key3: value3}}]}`

I thinking your algo should have iteration like this `for i in range(len(big_dict['StepOne']))` 

But I don't sure....

Comment: Yep, I ignored the initial default dict and worked with your original input. I have to go now, have a meeting. Will fix it later if nobody else does.

Comment: I changed your algorythm. Now it works correctly and get desired result. Many thanks!!!!! You helped me a lot! :)

Comment: Great :) How did you change it? I can add that to the answer. I was about to do it, back now.

Comment: I added string a top of your algo `for i in range(len()):` That's all :)

Comment: Yes, that would be necessary if you have more than one dictionary in that list. Otherwise, see the edit :)